# Acces to contact with android studio

Tags: android

I need to do an exercise in android studio. I have to access the data of my contacts, name, phone, and photo, birthday and put them in a sqllite database. Who can help me? I only took 5 months learning android

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow... simply search for this, you have so much tutorials for fetching contacts. 
the developer platform is a good way to start : https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a good read through [ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

Then read this [Content Providers, contracts and everything basic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContractClasses)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check udacity tutorials for start. It has plenty of code and  projects developed by google students.

https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851